# pass dynamic parameters to HostListener listener function in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am using `HostListener` function for `enter key` fro div element . My div elements is coming under `ngFor` in angular2 from there i need to pass the index value of `ngFor` to `HostListener` function.

My code :

**In HTML**

```
  <div *ngFor="let Add of Adds; let i = index">
       <div class="data_card"  (keydown)="edit($event,i)">
            {{Add.name}}
      </div>
</div>
```

**In Component**

```
 @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event','index'])
  edit(event: KeyboardEvent,index) {
    if (event && event.keyCode === 13) {
      consol.log(index)
    }
}
```

In this console log i am getting undefined value fro index. Please suggest how can i pass this parameter to this `HostListener` function.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: why do you need that index? and index of what div do you want? there will be many of them with `ngFor`

Comment: i need to know which div i selected and from which div i am going to click the enter button.

Comment: what do you mean `select a div`? are they contenteditable?

Comment: I have a list of items in div elements i need to change the selected div data to edit mode. That's why i am passing index value to HostListener function. Based on the index value i am changing the corresponding div to Edit mode

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: Please referrer this plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/UJOd7WPKAIotBykH1wje?p=preview

Comment: check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44773372/2545680)

Answer (score 1):

There are few things that you need to do:

1) Remove outer div and make `DIV` element selectable - add `tabindex` property:

```
    <div *ngFor="let data of jsondata; let i = index" (keydown)="handleKeyboardEvent($event,i)" tabindex="{{i}}">
        <h2>{{data.data1}}</h2>
    </div
```

2) Move `handleKeyboardEvent` to the App component and remove `@HostListener` binding:

```
export class App {
  jsondata:any = [];
  constructor() {...}
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent,index): void {
```

3) Add the event handling code:

```
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent,index): void {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      event.target.nextElementSibling.focus();
    }
}
```

Here is the [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4k5WMnCeGcYffYk0ZPzq?p=preview).

Comment: it's hard to come up with the right solution when you don't provide all the details... what do you mean by `down arrow selection`?

Comment: I need to select the div element like excel row selection.That's why used HostListener to select div and for enter key press

Comment: really thanks for your reply. Your giving great support for me. Thanks a lot. I am really stuck with this one. If you can help me out that's really thankful

Comment: if you click on the first div in the plunker and then press arrow down on your keyboard, you will see that it `console.logs` the event. you don't need host listener

Comment: But its not selecting the next div. Its maintain the first div i clicked

Comment: why would it select the next div? there's no code to do that. the question is about event listener

Comment: @user3541485, here is the [updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4k5WMnCeGcYffYk0ZPzq?p=preview), it selects the next element when you click ENTER

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147686/discussion-between-user3541485-and-maximus).

Comment: @user3541485, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work this way.

1. @HostListener register function to event. so does (event).
2. I am not sure that (keydown) exists (or can get extra param).
3. using @Hostlistener you cannot add custom params like that.
4. keydown on a div smells funny.

Comment: How can add custom parameters?

Comment: please explain what you are trying to do, it will be more easy to help you.

Comment: this my plunker. This what i am trying to do https://plnkr.co/edit/UJOd7WPKAIotBykH1wje?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Create directive and pass trouhgt `@Input obj: {item: Item, index: number };`

Then inside `@HostListener` just use `this.obj`